# efficiently insert dictionary into postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm passing an array of phone numbers to my api and would like to insert them into the database.

How can I do this the most efficient way possible?

It's currently a bit inefficient because it literally divides it into 500 insert statements if there are 500 contacts

This is how I'm inserting them..

```
   params[:phone_numbers].map{ |key, value| 

      UserContact.create({
          user: current_user,
          name: key,
          number: value
        })
    }
```

How do i optimize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is for the [activerecord-import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)

> Rails 5.0
>
> Use activerecord-import 0.11.0 or higher.
>
> Because plain-vanilla, out-of-the-box ActiveRecord doesn’t provide support for inserting large amounts of data efficiently. With vanilla ActiveRecord you would have to perform individual save operations on each model:

In Gemfile:

```
gem "activerecord-import"
```

In model:

```
require "activerecord-import"
```

In controller:

```
    user_contacts = []
    params[:phone_numbers].map{ |key, value| 
      user_contacts << UserContact.new(user: current_user,name: key,number: value)
  }

    UserContact.import user_contacts
```

For more information on activerecord-import please see its wiki: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki